# Random generated number are linear combination among them even if not specified

Tags: r, random, linear-algebra

I am simulating some draws using random numbers. Unlikely, the generated numbers **are not random as I would like**. In fact, I obtain that there are some linear combinations.

In details, I have the following starting data:

```r
start_vector = c(1,10,30,40,50,100) # length equal to 6
residual_of_model = 5
n = 1000 # Number of simulations
```

I try to simulate `n` observations from a random normal distribution for each of the `start_vector` elements, assuming it as a "random noise" to add to the original value (that is the one into `start_vector`):

```
out_vec <- matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = length(start_vector))
for (h_aux in 1:length(start_vector))
  {
    random_noise <- rnorm(n, 0, residual_of_model)
    out_vec[,h_aux] <- as.numeric(start_vector[h_aux]) + random_noise
  }
```

At this point, I obtain a matrix of size 6x1000. In theory, I assume all the columns and the rows in the matrix are linearly **independent** among them.

If I try to check it, using the `findLinearCombos()` function from the `caret` package I obtain that all the columns are indepent:

```
caret::findLinearCombos(out_vec)
```

If I try to evaluate the independence among the **rows**, using the following code:

```
caret::findLinearCombos(t(out_vec))
```

I obtain that **all the rows from 7 to 1000 are a linear combination of the first 6 (the length of `start_vector`**).

It is really strange in my opinion, I would like to not observe **no dependencies at all** since the rows are generated adding a random number using `rnorm`.

What am I missing? Is there some bug? Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the documentation the function is performing a QR decomposition and with only 6 columns the decomposition is eliminating all of the redundant equations ie row 7 to the end.

Comment: Your random 1000x6 matrix has full rank: 6. Your observation is consistent with linear algebra theory. If there were 7 free rows, the rank would be 7. This is not possible, the rank cannot exceed the number of columns.

Comment: ok, so the data are not correlated among them, it is just about the `findLinearCombos` function, right?